# Final enum in Thread's run() method

Tags: java, multithreading, enums, final

Why is the Elvis elvis definition has to be final to be used inside the Thread run() method?

```
 Elvis elvis = Elvis.INSTANCE; // ----> should be final Elvis elvis = Elvis.INSTANCE
 elvis.sing(4);

 Thread t1 = new Thread(
   new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
   elvis.sing(6); // --------> elvis has to be final to compile
  }
}
);


 public enum Elvis {
   INSTANCE(2);

   Elvis() {
     this.x = new AtomicInteger(0);
   }

   Elvis(int x){
     this.x = new AtomicInteger(x);
   }

   private AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger(0);

   public int getX() { return x.get(); }

   public void setX(int x) {this.x = new AtomicInteger(x);}

   public void sing(int x) {
      this.x = new AtomicInteger(x);
      System.out.println("Elvis singing.." + x);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the `elvis` variable is being captured by the anonymous inner class.

Java only (currently) captures variables *by value*. The compiler requires that the variable is final so that there can be no confusion about what will actually be used when the `run` method is called in the new thread: if you changed the value of `elvis` after creating the new thread but before starting it, what would you expect it to do?

This is a difference between the way that closures are effectively available in C# and Java. See my [closures article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) for more details of this. Java 7 will make closures more concise - I haven't been following along to know whether there will be any way of capturing the variable itself rather than a particular value.

Comment: Capturing the variable requires that the variable be actually stored in a capturable form. Doable for sure, but requires using a substantially different way of compiling the variables in the first place, so I can see the reluctance to just blunder in.

Comment: @Jon,@Donal The variable elvis itself is enum and it was meant to be a singleton. I would imagine that it can only be initialized once, and is effectively final?

Comment: @portoalet: No. The *variable* isn't an enum or a singleton. The *variable* is just a normal variable. The enum type itself may only be initialized once, but that's very different from whether a *variable* of that enum type can be assigned different values over its lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with threads and everything to do with constructing anonymous classes. The issue is that you are referencing a local variable from within the anonymous class. Now consider the following:

```
int c = 5;
Runnable r = new Runnable(){ public void run(){ System.out.println(c); } };
c = 6;
r.run();
```

In the snippet above, should the code print 5 or should it print 6? If r were to hold onto a reference to the current stack frame in order to resolve c, it  is conceivable that it could print 6. It is also conceivable that it could bind/capture the value of c earlier and print a 5. Java forces you to make c final so as to make this completely clear and also to absolve Java of the need to hang onto the current stack frame.

Comment: @Michael The variable elvis itself is enum and it was meant to be a singleton. I would imagine that it can only be initialized once, and is effectively final?

Comment: @portoalet, no, that is incorrect. For example, you can assign null to the variable and not just Elvis.INSTANCE, so it is still necessary to make it final.

Answer (score 1):

this isn't part of your question but i'm just curious: why are you reassigning Elvis.x if it's an AtomicInteger? that kind of misses the point of AtomicInteger's thread-safety. Consider rewriting:

```
public Elvis {

   final static private Elvis INSTANCE = new Elvis(2);
   static public Elvis getInstance() { return INSTANCE; }

   final private AtomicInteger x; 


   Elvis() { this(0); }

   Elvis(int x){ 
      this.x = new AtomicInteger(x);
   }

   public int getX() { return this.x.get(); }

   public void setX(int x) {this.x.set(x); }

   public void sing(int x) {
      setX(x);
      System.out.println("Elvis singing.." + x);
   }
 }
```

also since this has mutable content, it shouldn't be an enum.

Comment: I was playing with Enum Singleton and then I got the error compiling (as in the description above). So Elvis was meant to be a singleton with a mutable content. Oops, yes I should really use AtomicInteger.set method instead of creating a new Atomic Integer. Well spotted.